# Implementing RESTful web service with two parameters?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-1.0

I am writing Jersey RESTful web services. I have below two web methods.

```
@Path("/persons")
public class PersonWS {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonWS.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Person fetchPerson(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return personService.fetchPerson(id);
    }


}
```

Now i need to write one more web method which takes two parameters one is id and one more is name. It should be as below.

```
public Person fetchPerson(String id, String name){

}
```

How can i write a web method for above method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two choices - you can put them both in the path or you can have one as a query parameter.

i.e. do you want it to look like:

```
/{id}/{name}
```

or

```
/{id}?name={name}
```

For the first one just do:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/{name}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Person fetchPerson(
          @PathParam("id") Integer id,
          @PathParam("name") String name) {
    return personService.fetchPerson(id);
}
```

For the second one just add the name as a `RequestParam`. You can mix `PathParam`s and `RequestParam`s.

Comment: Tim, in case of first case do i need to send a request as: http://somedomain.com/App/persons/2/3    ? Thanks!

Comment: yeah..correct is there any way to pass the request as below? somedomain.com/App/persons/2_somename   ?

Comment: I've never tried it but I'd expect @Path("/{id}_{name}") to work. Really you are better off using a / though as it's what people will expect and because it will be escaped properly if there is a / in the name. I'm not sure off hand if _ will.

Comment: If i use @Path("/{id}_{name}") then do i need to split it by _ and get the params? Thanks!

Comment: No, the only change you make is to put an _ instead of the / in the @Path. No change to the code.